# Opened form won't reactivate after closing modal

Tags: vb.net

Within VB.NET Visual Studio 2013

I have an mdi application with several forms. Only one form is open at a given time, then while the user enters amounts by typing in the control, the form is recalculating itself constantly via code.

I also have buttons above (on the mdiform) to open modal dialogs to enter certain information; the information entered is somewhat long, but at the end what I need from the dialog is the result of certain calculation.

That number (the result) should be shown on the opened form after the user close the modal dialog; but it is not happening unless I press the enter key so the form is again recalculated.

I am looking for a way that the form recalculate when the user close the dialog.

I tried everything at my disposal, "Activate", "a public sub", "raise an event", and many others, but the form is not recalculating, what happens is that the cursor is there on the last control the user works in.

The only way to see those changes is reloading the form, but it is not elegant.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

PS. I have looked everywhere about how to do it, but seems I am looking on a haystack

Please need help badly.

ariel

Comment: If you have a problem with *code* you need to post *code* so we can see whats wrong in the *code*.  See [ask] and also take the [tour]

Comment: Definitely need a [MCVE].

Comment: Please ***post your code***...

Comment: The code is simple.

A MDI Form which calls a childform… the childform has several textboxes to enter information (mostly numbers), some other that are “read only” to show totals.

But also I have on the mdimain toolbar, buttons to open modal dialogs, and enter some numbers; after closing the dialog, the form should reactivate itself and rewrite the totals amounts.

But after closing the dialog, nothing happens on the childform, unless I enter a number or press enter. 

How to force the opened childform to redraw itselft.

Comment: They said _**post**_ your code, **not _describe_** your code! We need to see your exact code if we are to pinpoint any faults. Recreating it from a description will most likely result in non-problematic code, since we all have different ways of doing things.

Comment: Take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).